# Finding the sum number of values in a range within a limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table something like this:

```
       A             B
 1   13:15         12:00
 2   10:25
 3   14:15
 4   09:50
 5   15:30
 6   17:25
```

I am trying to find the number of values which is bigger than B1 in the range of A1:A6.
Final result should be "4", but I don't know how to find it as a newbie on Excel formulas.

Is it possible to find that result, within a single formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this formula in C1

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,">"&B1)
```

Screenshot

[image]